# Cоздание архива и добавление в него файлов при помощи php c сохранением прав доступа

Tags: php, zip, tar

Здравствуйте.

Исходя из условий моей задачи, мне нужно создать архив и добавить в него набор файлов. Это довольно просто решается при помощи ZipArchive.

Но проблема в том, что при добавлении файлов и последующей разархивации права доступа на файлы не сохраняются, т.е. у исходных файлов права 777, у файлов из архива - 644.

Каким образом можно создать архив с сохранением прав доступа на файлы? Возможно, есть какие-то библиотеки, позволяющие это сделать, буду рад любому решению.

Comment: @GhostSt, проще umask перед операцией менять. Есть какие-то расширения zip, которые сохраняют метаданные с правами, но это не гарантирует работу везде.

Comment: umask восстановливает предыдущие права доступа. А мне нужно, чтобы у файлов были полные права и после разархивации они сохранялись.

Comment: @GhostSt, ничего umask не восстанавливает. Он устанавливает права создаваемых файлов/директорий по умолчанию.

Comment: @Etki, так маска будет применяться ко всем созданным файлам. Пусть даже только к некоторому расширению, но всем файлам этого вида-племени, а ТС'у надо только архивированные файлы изменить.

Comment: @TheDoctor ну так после операции сбрасывать на дефолтный.

Comment: @Etki, никто не сказал, что у конечного юзера дефолтная маска стоит, плюс - по-моему это чуть геморойнее, чем сохранение прав и назначение их обратно после разархивации.  
Так же во время временной смены `unmask`, юзер может создавать ещё подобные файлы, поэтому они будут... другими :)

Comment: @TheDoctor дефолтный для юзера. alias тоже никто не отменял, чтобы каким-нибудь одним unzipu все это проворачивать.

Comment: Ребята, этот вариант не возможен потому, что данный архив будет разархивирован пользователем на каком-то постороннем сервере и у меня не будет доступа ни к файлам, ни к ssh. Потому-то и нужно сразу выставить права на файлы. Я уже перерыл кучу классов и расширений, но ниодно не позволяет изменять права на вложенные файлы. А текущие не сохраняются при добавлении в архив.

Comment: @GhostSt, есть подозрение, что придётся приложить к архиву `read.me`, где накарякать таблицу `file - permission`.

Comment: @TheDoctor. Вот тут я тебя не понял. Ты имеешь ввиду написать в read.me, что мол меняйте сами права на "такие-то"?

Comment: @GhostSt, угу.  
Просто я ни разу не видел у архиваторов поля "Разархивируй и установи права: ...".  
Так что некоторые действия как ни крути на юзера придётся переложить.  
Это если не вступить в лигу хардкорных хакеров и не написать обёртку.

Comment: Нет, это не выход. Некоторым изерам и разархивировать тяжело будет, что говорить о таких вещах, как chmod. 

Буду дальше землю носом ковырять, ведь при обычном архивировании права сохраняются. Значит, должно быть решение.

Comment: Можно шеллскрипт раздачи прав, на худой конец, в архив положить.

Answer (score 1):

Просто примени к архиву [`chmod()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php).
Можно так же заранее узнать эти права с помощью [`fileperms()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) и их передать в `chmod()`.

Comment: Проверл, увы, не работает. У архива 777, а после разархивации у файлов 644, у папок 755

Comment: Архиватор заправляет правами сам. Если хочешь, чтобы было, как тебе нужно, - делай, как я сказал, т.е. узнавай права, сохраняй их, после архивации меняй на то, что сохранил.  

Хотя как-то... говнокодерски звучит :)

Comment: Так в том то и проблема. Как изменить права на файлы, уже добавленные в архив?

Comment: @GhostSt, может, я туплю, но в архив - это один файл, к нему можно применить параметры доступа, а то, что в нём - это не файлы, а набор бит, к ним применить ничего нельзя, они только после разархивации станут полноценными членами братства файловой системы и при обряде совершеннолетия старейшина-драйвер_ФС даст им амулет прав доступа.

Comment: В принципе правильно, но речь не о том. То что у архива полные права (777), не означает что при извлечении файлов и них будут 777. Только что проверял. А мне нужно сохранить файлы в архив, так чтобы права на файлы сохранились. А не обнулялись до 644 или еще каких

Comment: Если я верно помню, то у никсов (сам на окошках, срач - лучше это или хуже - не люблю) есть некий `i-node`, в котором хранится информация, в т.ч. и о правах.  
Но я же выше писал - архиватор при извлечении даёт созданным файлам шаблонные права. Как поменять шаблон - я понятия не имею, да и вполне возможно это невозможно.